# postgres - select latest row in T1 just before timestamp for each row in T2

Tags: postgresql, gps, postgis, postgresql-9.3

I went over multiple questions but didn't find an answer. So I would appreciate an answer/link to a similar solution.
I have two tables: vehicles and events. Each vehicle having multiple GPS locations - say there are 4 vehicles in the toy example with 11 rows of GPS pings. but say for the toy test there are only 2 events.

For example vehicles (each row has unique `gid`, each vehicle has `vehicle_id`, also there is timestamp `date_time` and location `geom`):

```
SELECT gid, vehicle_id, date_time, geom FROM test_v vehicles ORDER BY 2,3,1;


   gid   | vehicle_id |      date_time      |                        geom                        
---------+------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 1257854 |        742 | 2009-06-06 19:02:01 | 01010000208A7D0000667CC002A7262741A444A87995324041
 1258089 |        742 | 2009-06-06 19:03:29 | 01010000208A7D00007ABCA45AD22227415A5ADEB5662E4041
 1258842 |        742 | 2009-06-06 19:07:23 | 01010000208A7D000083D5151C7414274196D0D21AE7284041
 1259213 |        742 | 2009-06-06 19:09:11 | 01010000208A7D000054160E1FE4052741D6E2E74CD2284041
 1257939 |       3055 | 2009-06-06 19:02:31 | 01010000208A7D0000327D6277FAF426418EA975ECB6504041
 1258898 |       3055 | 2009-06-06 19:07:41 | 01010000208A7D000003519FB5D5F6264166B1B943C3514041
 1259313 |       3425 | 2009-06-06 19:09:35 | 01010000208A7D0000418D23C296442741FCFCEF0069394041
 1258008 |       3426 | 2009-06-06 19:02:56 | 01010000208A7D000011958634824027414D5D3823A43C4041
 1258307 |       3426 | 2009-06-06 19:04:37 | 01010000208A7D0000C8017753AB38274175E727CBA43A4041
 1258744 |       3426 | 2009-06-06 19:06:56 | 01010000208A7D00005F9811D7903A274145135F0589384041
 1259018 |       3426 | 2009-06-06 19:08:13 | 01010000208A7D0000546B478B323A2741F4CB8DB6AD374041
(11 rows)
```

Events (unique `gid`, timestamp `t_date` and location `geom`):

```
SELECT gid, t_date, geom FROM test_c events;
  gid  |       t_date        |                        geom                        
-------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 13009 | 2009-06-06 19:04:31 | 01010000208A7D000034F06A423F18274123DF6756B8194041
 13021 | 2009-06-06 19:08:53 | 01010000208A7D0000D093E2A470FE26413E935C3A5E304041
```

**The idea is to understand what was the situation at time of each event, which vehicles were closer and later optimise allocation of vehicles to events.**

So I would like to join these tables so that I get for each event up to 4 rows (as number of vehicles) with last known position of each vehicle in time period of say 120 min before the event and until the event time, ordered by distance between the two. I want them in the same table so I could compare them by time, location, event type etc.

Now here is where I'm stuck. I know how to find the latest record of the vehicles ever in a specific time period (say up to 19:10). But this is not what I need as it cuts off the table of vehicles at time 19:10. But for event with `gid= 13009`  time was `19:04:31` so there might be included a position that is later than the event. What I want is latest position up to the time of the event that is different for each event obviously.

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
  v.vehicle_id
  , row_number() OVER() as gid
  , st_distance(v.geom, c.geom)::float4 as distance_m
  , c.gid as c_gid 
  , v.gid as v_gid
  , c.t_date as dt_c 
  , v.date_time as dt_v 
  , (c.t_date - v.date_time) as d_t
FROM (SELECT * FROM test_c ) as c
  ,  (SELECT * FROM test_v ORDER BY date_time DESC )  v
WHERE date_time >= (c.t_date -  '120 minute' :: INTERVAL) AND date_time <= (c.t_date + '0 minute' :: INTERVAL)
ORDER BY 1, 7  DESC , 5, 6 ,  c.geom <-> v.geom ASC ;
```

This is what I get:

```
 vehicle_id | gid | distance_m | c_gid |  v_gid  |        dt_c         |        dt_v         |   d_t    
------------+-----+------------+-------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------
        742 |   3 |     4748.6 | 13021 | 1258842 | 2009-06-06 19:08:53 | 2009-06-06 19:07:23 | 00:01:30
       3055 |   2 |    17125.8 | 13021 | 1258898 | 2009-06-06 19:08:53 | 2009-06-06 19:07:41 | 00:01:12
       3426 |   1 |    8515.65 | 13021 | 1259018 | 2009-06-06 19:08:53 | 2009-06-06 19:08:13 | 00:00:40
(3 rows)
```

I get incorrect dates and each vehicle is there only once (i guess because of `DISTINCT`) but I need them once per event with appropriate last location (so in this example 2 times for 2 events).

Ideally I would also like as the next step to have  3 latest positions for each vehicle, but perhaps that is for later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I understand:

```
select *
from (
    select distinct on (c.gid, v.vehicle_id)
        v.vehicle_id
        , row_number() over(order by v.gid) as gid
        , st_distance(v.geom, c.geom)::float4 as distance_m
        , c.gid as c_gid 
        , v.gid as v_gid
        , c.t_date as dt_c 
        , v.date_time as dt_v 
        , (c.t_date - v.date_time) as d_t
    from
        test_c c
        inner join 
        test_v v on
            date_time between c.t_date - '120 minute' :: interval and c.t_date
    order by c.gid, v.vehicle_id, v.date_time desc
) s
order by c_gid, distance_m
;
 vehicle_id | gid | distance_m | c_gid |  v_gid  |        dt_c         |        dt_v         |   d_t    
------------+-----+------------+-------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------
        742 |   8 |    10674.9 | 13009 | 1258089 | 2009-06-06 19:04:31 | 2009-06-06 19:03:29 | 00:01:02
       3426 |   5 |    18607.5 | 13009 | 1258008 | 2009-06-06 19:04:31 | 2009-06-06 19:02:56 | 00:01:35
       3055 |   4 |    28516.8 | 13009 | 1257939 | 2009-06-06 19:04:31 | 2009-06-06 19:02:31 | 00:02:00
        742 |  11 |     4748.6 | 13021 | 1258842 | 2009-06-06 19:08:53 | 2009-06-06 19:07:23 | 00:01:30
       3426 |  13 |    8515.65 | 13021 | 1259018 | 2009-06-06 19:08:53 | 2009-06-06 19:08:13 | 00:00:40
       3055 |  12 |    17125.8 | 13021 | 1258898 | 2009-06-06 19:08:53 | 2009-06-06 19:07:41 | 00:01:12
```

Comment: I don’t see anything that ensures that `DISTINCT ON (c.gid, v.vehicle_id)` will pick the record with the smallest `d_t`. Are you sure it will?

Comment: It does work and picks the last `dt_v`, thanks @Clodoaldo Neto. Good point though @Dario : probably could just do `WHERE v.date_time<=c.t_date` and pick the minimal `d_t`

Comment: @Lizardie It will always pick the max d_t. That's a `distinct on` feature when issued with a proper `order by`. Check the manual.

Comment: @ Clodoaldo Neto tnx, yes it will pick the max `dt_v` and thus min `d_t` (that is distance in time from event to last known position)

Comment: Here is the link to [the relevant doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Comment: I checked and it does work because of a _very_ specific behavior of PostgreSQL. Go figure that other dialects of SQL don’t even accept `ORDER BY` in subqueries, or specifically `ORDER BY` together with `DISTINCT`. PostgreSQL does accept `ORDER BY` together with `DISTINCT` only if  the `DISTINCT ON` expressions match the leftmost `ORDER BY` expressions (just as here). This is subtly non-portable, but who cares? The OP asked for PostgresSQL, not portable SQL. Thanks @ClodoaldoNeto for showing this feature.